# Android debugging on device with usb tether test wifi

Tags: wifi, adb, tethering

In order for adb to recognize my device LG G4 I needed to select USB tethering. With this setting on, I am unable to maintain a wifi connection. I am trying to do some testing with wifi and want to have access to the log.

I thought maybe I could use adb over wifi but I want to see logs for connecting and disconnecting to wifi, do once I disconnect from wifi I loose my log.

Comment: enable `usb debugging` and use adb over usb. what is the problem ?

Comment: In order for my computer to recognize my device so far the only solution I found was to turn on usb tethering. When tethering is on it wouldn't let me also be connected to wifi.

Comment: That is strange, if you have installed proper usb driver installed and adb version is up to date, it should detect adb devices over usb.

Comment: I will continue to experiment, I saw things mention using a powered USB hub and some other things to try. It was just that the tethering worked right away.

Thanks for showing interest in helping me with this problem.